# What is the css selector for an element with a class and an attribute in sencha touch

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, css-selectors, sencha-touch

I used to have a code that checks any previous element with a corresponding css class and an attribute which is...

```
var previousEl = el.prev('.line[@id]');
where line is a class and id is an attribute
```

this code worked in Ext but when I tried running the same code in sencha-touch, I get a "Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12".

I checked the dom and I have verified that there is a previous sibling with the class and the attribute id.

Can somebody help me out as to why this selector does not work anymore?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dropping the `@`? They took it out from jQuery at some point of time, and reading the Sencha docs it would seem that they did the same in Ext JS.

```
var previousEl = el.prev('.line[id]');
```

Comment: sencha touch documentation says "The use of @ and quotes are optional.", so it should work with or without

Comment: @at0mzk: Ah I see. Still worth a try though.

Comment: By not using the @ made the selector work. I am not sure why it does not work with the @.

Comment: @Jaime: They probably stopped supporting XPath selectors.

Answer (score 0):

unlike Ext JS which seems to have its own selector code DomQuery in sencha touch seems to rely on document.querySelectorAll

see the select method in
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/source/DomQuery.html#method-Ext.DomQuery-is

and that method is throwing "SYNTAX_ERR exception if the specified group of selectors is invalid." see
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll

probably thats the exception you get. try to use selectors that make that function happy

Comment: now this is a wild guess: maybe you need use '*.line[id]'. also see http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/